# Context.startService(intent) or startService(intent)

Tags: android, service

What is the difference between `Context.startService(intent)` and `startService(intent)` and does it matter which one is used?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is only one `startService()` method. `startService()` is a method on the `Context` class, available to all subclasses of `Context`, like `Activity` or `Service`.

Comment: Why some use Context.startService(intent) instead just startService(intent)?

Comment: You would have to ask them. It is not necessary.

Comment: see my answer below to understand why and when we use Context @mnish

Answer (score 2):

As Commonsware said there is only one `startService()`. That is `Context.startService(intent)`.

Your main activity program itself is an instance of `Context` and you do not need to explicity call the method (startService) with a `Context`.

It is like calling a method of a class within the class itself.

Answer (score 0):

**Explanation**

Everyone in **Android** may know how to use `Adapter`. We can create seperate class for them. it will make our coding more simpler to handle and understand. But when we create these classes seperately. They need a **Context** (`Calling on behalf`) . So in that case we pass the context of the activity in their constructor. In that way Android knows that we are calling this on behalf of which activity.

We can't call

```
getSystemService(Context...)//blah bhal
```

in seperate adapter class but we can pass the context in the Adapter constructor and can call it like this..

```
context.getSystemService(Context....)//
```

Call your adapter like this

```
ArticleAdapter adapter = new ArticleAdapter(context, list);

                    list_of_article.setAdapter(adapter);
```

and get The context like this..

**ArticleAdapter.class**

```
public class ArticleAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    Context context;

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>  list;

    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public ArticleAdapter(Context context,
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list)
    {
        this.context = context;

        this.list = list;

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position)
    {
        return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View view = convertView;

        if (view == null)
        {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_article, parent, false);
        }

        HashMap<String, String> map = list.get(position);

        TextView Title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_title);

        TextView ByWhom = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_bywhom);

        ImageView Img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_img);

        ProgressBar bar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

        TextView TextUnderImg = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.item_text_under_imag);

        TextView Comments = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_comment);

        TextView TableView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_tableview);

        TextView ReadMore = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_readmore);

        context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);// if you want these service you must have to call it using context.

        Title.setText(map.get("title"));

        ByWhom.setText(map.get("publishdate"));

        return view;
    }

}
```

Comment: Do not hold onto an `Activity` in an `AsyncTask`. If that activity is destroyed (BACK button, configuration change, etc.) while the `AsyncTask` is running, now the `AsyncTask` will be holding onto an invalid activity. In particular, **never** refer to an activity from `doInBackground()`, as the activity is in an indeterminate state while the background thread is running. In this case, the `AsyncTask` should be holding onto a `LayoutInflater` and a `ConnectivityService`.

Comment: I understand @CommonsWare But according to Adapter . Am i having the right concept about using it in Adapter

Comment: Yeesh, I need more sleep. My apologies. In this case, I'd probably still pass in the `LayoutInflater` and `ConnectivityService`, but I am much less concerned about any problems. Again, I apologize for my mistake.